# C# cannot convert from 'float' to 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Point'

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm Trying to make a rougelike in C# using Monogame and RogueSharp.

here is some of the code I have in Draw()

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            _spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);

            int sizeOfSprites = 64;
            float scale = .25f;
            foreach (Cell cell in _map.GetAllCells())
            {
            // error in the line below    
            Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle position = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle(cell.X * sizeOfSprites * scale, cell.Y * sizeOfSprites * scale);
                if (cell.IsWalkable)
                {
                    _spriteBatch.Draw(floorSprite, position, null, Color.White, 0f, new Vector2(scale, scale), 0.0f, 0f);
                }
                else
                {
                    _spriteBatch.Draw(wallSprite, position, null, Color.White, 0f, new Vector2(scale, scale), 0.0f, 0f);
                }
            }

            _spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
```

Returns:

Argument 2: cannot convert from 'float' to 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Point'

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'float' to 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Point'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Rectangle` constructor either takes `(Point location, Point size)` or `(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)` but not `(Float, Float)` (what would that even mean?) - See [docs](https://docs.monogame.net/api/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle.html#Microsoft_Xna_Framework_Rectangle__ctor_Microsoft_Xna_Framework_Point_Microsoft_Xna_Framework_Point_).

So, two issues here:

- You need four values to uniquely specify a rectangle in 2D space, not two. `Rectangle` does that using X and Y of the top-left corner as well as width and height.
- The `Rectangle` constructor expects those values as integers and not floats.

Looking at your code, I'm *guessing* that you want to create a rectangle that has `sizeOfSprites * scale` as length of both sides, in which case you'd need to specify the size as follows:

```cs
int scaledSize = (int)(sizeOfSprites * scale);
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle position = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle(
  cell.X * scaledSize,
  cell.Y * scaledSize,
  scaledSize,
  scaledSize
);
```

I noticed `Cell` also has integer coordinates and you only use floats for the 0.25 part, so you can simply store the size as integer too. If you don't intend to later make these variables dynamic, the fastest way would be to use `const int scaledSize = 16;` in the first place.

Comment: That works now! tysm!

Comment: The  `(int)Math.Floor()` call is redundant.  Use only the cast `(int)`.  Negative positions are off screen and not relevant.  In games, execution speed, less than 16ms, is of utmost importance. Sub-pixel accuracy is only needed for anti-aliasing, not for general drawing.

Answer (score 1):

You want to minimize the operations performed in `Draw()`. `Draw()` is a blocking call, meaning the process will wait(ie hang) on its completion.

I would suggest pre-multipying `sizeOfSprites * scale` as a constant, if it does not change:

`const int SIZE = 16; // 64 * .25`

```
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle position = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle(
  (int)(cell.X * SIZE),  (int)(cell.Y * SIZE),  SIZE, SIZE);
);
```

For simple games the 16.6666667 ms (60 FPS) time limit per frame is not an issue, but as games grow, they may hit the limit.

I am not advocating over-optimization. Most likely in this case on an X86/X64 processor, the memory look-ups may be cached, but what about mobile or console applications where the cache structure/layout may be different?

Making unneeded function calls only adds to the time budget.(`Floor()` and `Round()`)

Each function call necessarily adds the current state context pushes, copying any passed variables, and popping the context state + results. Lots of unneeded memory accesses.